# 'str' object is not callable when returning a string in classes

Tags: python, class

```
class BigThing:
    
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
    
    def size(self):
        if isinstance(self.size, int):
            return self.size
        else:
            return len(self.size)
    
class BigCat(BigThing):
    
    def __init__(self, size, weight):
        super().__init__(size)
        self.weight = weight
        
    def size(self):
        if (self.weight > 15) and (self.weight <= 20):
            return "Fat"
        elif (self.weight > 20):
            return "Very Fat"
        else:
            super().size(self)

def main():
    cutie = BigCat("mitzy", 22)
    print(cutie.size())

main()
```

expected output: Very Fat

current output: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I don't know how to fix it and there is no logical problems that prevents the code from running.

Comment: Note how in `BigThing`, `self.size` refers to both the attribute set in `__init__`, *and* the method (not at once though). Methods and "non-method attributes" don't have separate namespaces. One can and will overwrite the other.

Comment: the overwriting size function is on purpose.

Comment: If you overwrite the method with a number, you can't call it as a function any more.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `@property`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a property to implement an attribute as a method.

In order to make `size` a property, you must use a different name for the internal attribute that holds the value. A common convention is to prefix it with `_`.

```
class BigThing:
    
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size

    @property
    def size(self):
        if isinstance(self._size, int):
            return self._size
        else:
            return len(self._size)

    @size.setter
    def size(self, size):
        self._size = size
```

Comment: The reason why this works is because you renamed `self.size` to `self._size`. It has nothing to do with `@property`

Comment: @ThomasWeller That's part of how you use `@property`.

Comment: The reason why this works is because you renamed self.size to self._size. It has nothing to do with @property, why this is work after that? it is only changing the name of the argument.

Comment: You have to rename the attribute so it doesn't conflict with the property name. You can't use the same name for both.